# Assigning numbers to data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to assign a number to each entry (an id number). I want the id number to be the same as the number of lines in the text file the data is saved to. So for the first entry the id number would be 1 the second entry would have an id number of 2 etc. 
Below is the code for the data that is entered. Its adds a line each time so each entry is on a different line (\n).
The first line is for the id number creation. It works if a file has already been created.
For the first entry it creates the file that is not there. Is there a way to automatically create an empty file or get the number to return no file as 0? so my id generator works how i want it to.

```
number = sum(1 for line in open('Surname')) + 1
def enter():
    surname = (input("Enter surname: "))
    filename = ("Surname");
    with open (filename, "a") as f:
        f.write (str(number)+ " " + surname + "\n")
enter()
```

Comment: Yes, change `"a"` to `"a+"`

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to do this to create an empty file for the number counter to work.

```
filename = ("Surname");
with open (filename, "a") as f:
    f.write("")
```